# Use a .Properties File to pass values to a Batch File

Tags: backup, batch-file, mysql

What we’d like to do is to eliminate the need for embedding the User_ID, User Password, Host Server Name, and Specific Database names into our batch file when automating a backup from our MySQL Server.

Here’s the batch file that I use now:

```
:: Properties File for Batch

@echo off

cls

c:

cd\

cd program files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE

mysqldump -uroot -pRoot_Password -hHost_Server_Name DB_Nbr1 > c:\MySQLBackup\DB_Nbr1_BU_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.SQL


mysqldump -uroot -pRoot_Password -hHost_Server_Name DB_Nbr2 > c:\MySQLBackup\DB_Nbr2_BU_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.SQL


mysqldump -uroot -pRoot_Password -hHost_Server_Name DB_Nbr3 > c:\MySQLBackup\DB_Nbr3_BU_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.SQL


mysqldump -uroot -pRoot_Password -hHost_Server_Name test > c:\MySQLBackup\test_BU_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.SQL
```

What we want to do is to have a separate   “.properties “ file which would store the User ID; Password; Host Server Name; etc.

Also, if we could get a listing of the directories underneath a given path, which would then loop the appropriate # of times, that would be ideal.

Comment: Wasssupppppp Skibear!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this like so...

Create your file list (or .properties file) containing the **username**, **password**, **hostname** and **databasename** in the same one file with the values of each of those on the first line, and each separated by a comma (i.e. `<Username>,<Password>,<Hostname>,<DatabaseName>`).

**FileList Content Example - Line One**

`MyUserName,MyP@ssw0rd!,MyHostName,MyDatabaseName`

---

Then have a batch script using [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and set the delimiter to a comma that uses the correlated file list to then call the other (MySQL backup) batch script passing the arguments in accordingly.

**Batch script using the filelist values and calling the MySQL backup script**

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-4 DELIMS=," %%F IN (C:\MyFileList.properties) DO CALL "C:\Path\BatchScript.cmd" %%F %%G %%H %%I
```

---

You'd need to change the MySQL backup script to be able to handle the arguments that are passed in by the calling script as in the below example.

**Batch script handling passed arguments**

```
@ECHO OFF

CLS

SET User=%1
SET Pass=%2
SET Host=%3
SET DBName=%4

CD /D "C:\program files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE"

mysqldump -u%User% -p%Pass% -h%Host% %DBName% > C:\MySQLBackup\%DBName%_BU_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.SQL

GOTO EOF
```

---

Another method would just be to use the above script that handles the passed in arguments, and then just pass those arguments in at the level you may have these scripts scheduled to pass in the values accordingly.

For example your scheduling software may have the ability to pass arguments so you'd use the below syntax examples with this method perhaps and the script would change the variable based on the argument value to you pass into the script.

1. `"C:\Path\MySQLDBBackup.cmd" <Username> <Password> <Hostname> <DatabaseName>`
2. `"C:\Path\MySQLDBBackup.cmd" "<Username>" "<Password>" "<Hostname>" "<DatabaseName>"`

---

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)